# What is the highest possible completion percentage, and how do you get over 100%?

Tags: limbo

I'm at 98%, missing the speedrun achievement, and I see percentages from 102% to 112% on the leaderboards. What is the highest non-glitched completion percentage possible, and what adds to the completion percentage over 100%? Easter eggs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum legitimate percentage has been confirmed by [Playdead](http://limbogame.org/2010/07/all-super-secrets-found/) to be **111**. Percentages with 112 and more involves downloading someone else's game save, and no matter the reason, is against Microsoft's TOS.

[Supercheats.com](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/limbo/leaderboards/) explains the 111 percent as follows:

> Completing the game will net you a 76 percent rating on the
>   leaderboards. You get 2 percent for each achievement, making a total
>   of 22 percent (if you already have the achievements this is included
>   in the bundle). You are given another 2 percent if it is a second play
>   through, or if you are playing a chapter having already completed the
>   game. Finally, you get 1 percent with each secret egg.
>
> As you mathematicians will have realised, the total adds up to 100
>   percent not including the secret eggs. That means that if you have
>   already completed the game with all achievements, you are guaranteed
>   to get 100 percent on your next playthrough. The secret eggs add up to
>   11 percent, meaning the best you can get on the leaderboards is 111
>   percent!

You may also want to check this [forum thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showpost.php?p=3355859&postcount=74) for some details about how they get 112 or more.