# Secret eggs in Limbo for Xbox One

Tags: version-differences, limbo

I completed Limbo on Xbox 360 back in the day, and picked up most of the secret eggs that give you a [completion percentage above 100%](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/what-is-the-highest-possible-completion-percentage-and-how-do-you-get-over-100).

Now that the game is out for Xbox One, I decided to buy it there as well because I like it so much. I have completed the game on that platform too now, and I have picked up all of the eggs that award achievements.

However, I am unable to find any of the secret eggs that only award a higher completion percentage.

Have they been removed from the next-gen version of the game? Are they located in new hiding spots?

Comment: There are no longer any achievements for the eggs in the Xbox One version, so I assume the developers took them out.

Comment: @deutschZuid Where do you get that from? [There are still achievements for the regular eggs](http://www.trueachievements.com/LIMBO/achievements.htm), and I have picked them all up. [There were never achievements for the super secret eggs in the previous version](http://www.trueachievements.com/LIMBO-Xbox-360/achievements.htm) (and there still aren't now); finding these used to only give a completion percentage above 100%. Edited my post to clarify what eggs I'm talking about.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/limbo-hidden-egg-guide/) detailing all the secret eggs.

Comment: This video details how to find the hidden eggs that unlock Achievements. Those eggs are in both the Xbox 360 and Xbox One versions of the game. The eggs I'm talking about, however, are the secret eggs that do not unlock Achievements, but only [add to your completion percentage](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/what-is-the-highest-possible-completion-percentage-and-how-do-you-get-over-100). [Here's a video detailing the secret egg locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW0FuIqWTdw&list=PL48B9A5816EDECEB6) in the 360 version. I can't find them on the Xbox One.

Comment: @tobiasvl edited my answer to reflect what you need

Comment: Thank you, those are the correct eggs. However, I still can't find them in the Xbox One version.

Comment: I've done some more looking and I'm sorry to say it looks as though there are no guides as to the xbo/ps4 version of those eggs